# Is there a possibility to find the average discrete probability effect of a factor while factoring in another variable in R?

Tags: r, stata, margins

In Stata, the following command can be used. Assume that I want to estimate the average discrete probability effect of doing sports while controlling for age.

```
margins, at(age=(25(5)65)) over(sports)
```

Can this be reproduced in R with the margins-package?

I tried multiple specifications with the margins-package, and read through the documentation but have not found any solutions yet.

Comment: `emmeans` is the established package to estimate marginal means and contrasts from models so look at its documentation.  There is a newer one but I can't remember its name.

Comment: There is a newer package called `marginaleffects` which should be able to do this, too.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example in such questions.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not super familiar with the `over()` option in Stata. If you describe the specific mathematical quantity that is calculated and supply a reproducible example with Stata output and public data, I may be able to confirm whether this is possible with the `marginaleffects` package in R.

For reference, you can see side-by-side examples of `marginaleffects` and Stata for many equivalent calls in this vignette: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/alternative_software.html#stata

From what I gather from the Stata docs, the code you post estimates the predicted probabilities of the outcome, estimated over a counterfactual grid of age values, and averaged across categories of one predictor. An analogous example in `marginaleffects` would be:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
mod <- glm(vs ~ mpg * factor(cyl), data = mtcars, family = binomial)

# equivalent to ,at() option in Stata
avg_predictions(mod, by = "cyl", newdata = datagridcf(mpg = seq(10, 33, by = 5)))
 
#  cyl Estimate Pr(>|z|)    2.5 % 97.5 %
#    4 8.85e-01    0.269 1.70e-01  0.997
#    6 5.47e-01    0.835 1.70e-01  0.877
#    8 1.17e-09    0.998 2.22e-16  1.000
# 
# Columns: cyl, estimate, p.value, conf.low, conf.high

# equivalent to ,dydx at() option in Stata
avg_slopes(mod, by = "cyl", newdata = datagridcf(mpg = seq(10, 33, by = 5)))

#  Term          Contrast cyl  Estimate Std. Error         z Pr(>|z|)     2.5 %    97.5 %
#   cyl mean(6) - mean(4)   4 -3.72e-01   2.30e-01 -1.62e+00   0.1050 -8.22e-01  7.78e-02
#   cyl mean(6) - mean(4)   6 -3.72e-01   2.30e-01 -1.62e+00   0.1050 -8.22e-01  7.78e-02
#   cyl mean(6) - mean(4)   8 -3.72e-01   2.30e-01 -1.62e+00   0.1050 -8.22e-01  7.78e-02
#   cyl mean(8) - mean(4)   4 -8.82e-01   2.25e-01 -3.93e+00   <0.001 -1.32e+00 -4.42e-01
#   cyl mean(8) - mean(4)   6 -8.82e-01   2.25e-01 -3.93e+00   <0.001 -1.32e+00 -4.42e-01
#   cyl mean(8) - mean(4)   8 -8.82e-01   2.25e-01 -3.93e+00   <0.001 -1.32e+00 -4.42e-01
#   mpg mean(dY/dX)         4  4.18e-03   3.17e-02  1.32e-01   0.8949 -5.79e-02  6.62e-02
#   mpg mean(dY/dX)         6 -5.14e-02   2.92e-02 -1.76e+00   0.0785 -1.09e-01  5.85e-03
#   mpg mean(dY/dX)         8 -3.19e-21   2.25e-06 -1.42e-15   1.0000 -4.41e-06  4.41e-06
# 
# Columns: term, contrast, cyl, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted, predicted_hi, predicted_lo
```

Edit: Note that there may be some numerical differences between Stata and R due to the order of backtransformation and averaging. You may want to try different values of the `type` argument ("link" or "response").